# Sending file from server to client threads

Tags: multithreading, visual-studio, c++-cli

I have two programs, one for client and one for server. They can talk to each other with a chat using Threads.

After I added two buttons, one for client and one for server to send file from server to client.

When I connect the client to server I start the Thread which waits to receive something with `recv()` function.

The problem is that when I want to send a file to client because the thread is awake the transfer does not work.

When I do not use threads the transfer works. 
My question is: Can I from a button click to stop that Thread?

PS: I am a begginer in Threads

This is my code with Threads:

```
    delegate System::Void PrintStringDel(String^ str);

        void PrintString(String^ str) {
            txtReceive->Text += str;
            txtReceive->SelectionStart = txtReceive->Text->Length;
            txtReceive->ScrollToCaret();
        }
void ReceiveThread() {
         int ByteReceived;
        char buff[1024];

        while(true) {
           ByteReceived = recv(SendingSocket, buff, sizeof(buff), 0);

           if(ByteReceived > 0) {
                PrintStringDel^ print = gcnew PrintStringDel(this, &Form1::PrintString);
                String^ text = gcnew String(buff);
                txtReceive->BeginInvoke(print, text);
           }
        }
    }
```

on Connect() client

```
        ...
Threading::ThreadStart^ ts = gcnew Threading::ThreadStart(this,
                                           &Form1::ReceiveThread);
        Threading::Thread^ t = gcnew Threading::Thread(ts);
        t->Start();
```

Comment: This is not C++, but C++/CLI. `C++-CLI` is the correct tag.

Comment: Side note: If you have two processes (programs) start the communication without using threads (in each process)

Comment: Are you asking 'how to stop a thread?'